# php jquery call from controller

Tags: php, jquery, symfony

I am making an application in Symfony2. When I want to run a logging jQuery code to also change the stylesheets according to the web user accessing the page. When a user calls the method `AuthenticationHandlerInterface` but you can run code from there?

The idea is to get the user logged consult the stylesheet name and execute the jQuery code to change the CSS link href attribute.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but it's difficult to understand exactly what you want, but let me try: You want to call a method in your Symfony backend (`AuthenticationHandlerInterface`) which, based on who is logged in, will change which stylesheets are used? If so, I don't think you would need to use jQuery for that, but rather just the code in the template that handles the header of a page.

Comment: thanks jakerella for your answer. T